# Code in comments does not work

Tags: bug, comments

In the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) it says that you need to

> Indent four spaces to create an escaped block

This however does not work. [In a comment I wrote XML with 4 spaces indentation, plus a language definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324547/can-pure-svg-document-specify-a-favicon-ico#comment-32022092). This is the actual text:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>De mægtige vikinger</title>
<defs>
<xhtml:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</defs>
</svg>
```

Also, spaces for indentation counts as characters. Meaning you can write more code if you don't bother formatting it. This is counter intuitive to have easy to read and accessible comments.

The resolution should be to implement a robust code formatter and not count formatting instructions in the sum of how many characters a user can write.

**UPDATE**
All answers up till now has been misleading. Please follow the links and check the support page. It might also help to read the comment discussed to see why it's relevant and can not be inline.

Comment: This is the actual text:
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <title>De mægtige vikinger</title>
      <defs>
        <xhtml:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      </defs>
    </svg>

Comment: Where is it stated that comments support full markdown? The comment helptext is quite clear that it only supports a limited subset of markdown. Multi-line comments, let alone code in comments, is not supported.

Comment: Code is meant to be in posts (questions and answers) rather than in comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when you click help (next to the comment text area) and then *Learn more...* you get to the help page I linked to. If this is wrong - it should be fixed.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter: The small help text starts with: *Comments use mini-Markdown formatting*. The 'Learn more...' page starts with *Comments support only bold, italic, code and links* followed with samples for all four of those types of formatting. The code sample uses `\`` backticks.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter When I click learn more on a comment I get sent to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting, which is correct. I don't get sent to the quoted link

Comment: You're right. I misread the information as it's on the same page. Changing this to feature request.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Its usually best to ask a whole new question if you want to fundamentally change it

Comment: I've just updated the question. @RichardTingle Do you think it's fundamentally changed?

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Well all the answers are now no longer applicable so I would say yes it has

Comment: @RichardTingle I see your point. I'll create a new *question*.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter I think thats the best way forward, that way you get a clean slate to make your case. I've rolled this back to its previous version in that case

Comment: @RichardTingle How do I get my update text so I don't have to write it all again?

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Its all saved in the revision history. Which you can get to by clicking on "edited 31 minutes ago", or by following [this link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/216927/revisions). Clicking edit on your revision gives you the exact markdown it had at the time

Comment: @RichardTingle as a side note: Because this question had a `<!-- language: lang-xml -->`, the code is hidden. It kinda makes it difficult to see what the question is about.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter It was because of the `<pre> <code>` in the "Indent four spaces to create an escaped block". I wasnt certain why that was there so I left it in, but it caused assorted problem further down.I've removed the `<pre> <code>` and now its all there

Comment: @RichardTingle Hmm in my tests it still doesn't work with `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` in front of the code block.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter I think I know the problrm, do you mind if I play around with your other question (because the markup isn't shown on preview I might get it wrong at first). I believe it is because <!-- language: lang-xml --> isn't code and shouldn't  be part of the code block

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't mind - go ahead. I got the language definition from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting, although I'm not sure if XML is supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Comments support only some markdown

Because comments do not support new lines they also don't support indentation. You can get limited code formatting using mini markdown and the backtick code format:

```
This comment has code: `int a=0;`, the variable `a` is set to 0
```

Becomes

This comment has code: `int a=0;`, the variable `a` is set to 0.

### Code in comments shouldn't be overused

However, significant amounts of code should not be found in comments, since comments are to request clarification/critique to existing posts, not to offer solutions

### Where to find more information

In addition to the [formatting help document you quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) the comments come with their own help, which you can access when adding a new comment (see below).

[image]

Comment: This comment has code: `int a=0;`, the variable `a` is set to 0

Comment: The code in the comment is the minimum required to ask why the answer did not work. Inline code is too restrictive. In general markup languages just requires more text, than programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Click 'show help' next to the comment box for a guide to mini-markdown formatting in comments:

[image: Show Help]